# How to replace the Dojo construct().place() with Vanilla JS?

Tags: javascript, dojo

How can I replace Dojo's `DomConstruct.place()` with vanilla Javascript in the following snippet?

```js
DomConstruct.place(this._rect, this._widget._xComponent, "after");
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend learning about DOM manipulation, specifically moving and placing elements, [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Client-side_web_APIs/Manipulating_documents#moving_and_removing_elements).

That said, in order to replace Dojo's `DomConstruct.place()` with vanilla Javascript you would need to do something like the following:

```js
this._widget._xComponent.appendChild(this._rect);
```

You may need to reference the nodes differently or select the nodes by id using  `document.getElementById("myId")`, but `appendChild(node)` is what you are looking for.